# Returning from bash script that invokes a python script

Tags: python, bash

I have a bash script (`Controller.sh`) that invokes a python script (`MyDaemon.py`). The latter takes an argument and a command, and can be invoked from the command line like so:

```
/usr/bin/python /opt/stuff/MyDaemon.py -p Blue start
```

or

```
/usr/bin/python /opt/stuff/MyDaemon.py -p Blue stop
```

or

```
/usr/bin/python /opt/stuff/MyDaemon.py -p Blue status
```

I am attempting to get `Controller.sh` to invoke `MyDaemon.py` and then exit with a status. The python script should be kicked off and `Controller.sh` should return. This is my `Controller.sh` code:

```
COLOR=$1
COMMAND=$2

DIRNAME=`dirname $0`
RESULT="/tmp/$COLOR.$COMMAND.result"

# remove any old console output
rm -f $RESULT 2>/dev/null

#start with CPU affinity for anything other than CPU 0.
sudo taskset -c 1-8 /usr/bin/python /opt/stuff/MyDaemon.py -p $COLOR $COMMMAND</dev/null >$RESULT 2>&1

STATUS=$?

# print output
cat $RESULT

# check on success
if [ $STATUS -ne 0 ]
then
        echo "ERROR: $COLOR $COMMAND failed"
        exit 1
fi
```

Now, if on the command line I invoke `Controller.sh blue start` it kicks off the python script, but `Controller.sh` does not return a status. On the other hand, if I run the following it does return:

```
[nford@myserver]# sudo taskset -c 1-8 /usr/bin/python /opt/stuff/MyDaemon.py -p blue start</dev/null >/tmp/blah.log 2>&1
Started with pid 1326
[nford@myserver]#
```

I am forced to conclude that there is something about the bash script that is preventing it from returning.

It should be noted that `MyDaemon.py` does fork processes, which is why I need to redirect output. It should also be noted that I'm lifting the majority of this from another script that does something similar with a php script; some of the meaning I'm fuzzy on (such as `STATUS=$?`). That said, even if I cut out everything after the `sudo taskset` invocation line, it still fails to return cleanly. How do I get the bash script to properly execute this command?

Post-Script: I'm a little baffled how this question is 'too specific' and was down-voted/voted to close. In an attempt to be crystal clear; I'm trying to understand the differences in how a forking process script runs in the context of the command line versus a bash script. I've provided a specific example above, but this is a general concept.

UPDATE:
This results when I run the script using `bash -x`, further showing that it dies on the `sudo taskset` line. The fact it's left off the `start` command is confusing.

```
[nford@myserver]# bash -x Controller.sh Blue start
+ COLOR=Blue
+ COMMAND=start
++ dirname Controller.sh
+ DIRNAME=.
+ RESULT=/tmp/Blue.start.result
+ rm -f /tmp/Blue.start.result
+ sudo taskset -c 1-8 /usr/bin/python /opt/stuff/MyDaemon.py -p Blue
```

UPDATE:
`bash -x` reveals the problem: the `start` command is not being passed through: a typo in the variable name produces as silent bash error. Takeaway: use `bash -x` for debugging!

Comment: I don't think so... `cat` will, I believe read `$RESULT` into `$STATUS`. Then I check to see if `$STATUS` is empty. Regardless, the problem comes before that point. I include it here to show what I'm trying to do.

Comment: I believe that every script has a return status unless it's still running. Are you unable to get any return status?

Comment: The bash script appears to continue to run, even though the underlying script should just pass control back. Therefore there is no return status.

Comment: Are you sure the underlying script returns?

Comment: I included that in the post: observe the line starting with `sudo taskset` can be run on the command line and return (I give example output towards the bottom of the post).

Comment: Have tried running your script like ``bash -x Controller.sh xx zz``. Also in your example on the command line you didn't ``echo $?`` after running ``sudo taskset...`` ; a message at the end of your script saying ``echo DONE`` might help you as well.

Comment: What does bash -x do? If I eliminate everything after the `sudo taskset` line in the bash script I get the same result: the script runs but because the python script doesn't quit, the bash script doesn't either.

Comment: @sotapme Argh! You totally saved me! It's a typo: COMMMAND versus COMMAND. Can you post an answer so I can give you credit?

Comment: Typo's are the best bugs...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of your typo - You should use `set -u` at the top of your scripts, it's a life saver and stops sleepless nights as well as negating the pulling of hair.

`set -u` would have given you...

```
myscript.sh: line 11: COMMMAND: unbound variable
```

Remember you can run scripts like so `bash -u myscript.sh arg1 arg2` likewise with `-x`, they both help it tracking down script issues.